# Understanding two dimensional arrays

Tags: c

Here's the code and wondering if you can help me understand it.

```
/* Two dimensional array */

#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i, j, sum[2], mean[2];
    int mark[3][2] = { { 34, 56}, { 48, 65}, { 53, 59} };

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        sum[j] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            sum[j] = sum[j] + mark[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        mean[j] = sum[j] / 3;
    printf("Average mark in Mathematics is %d\n", mean[0]);
    printf("Average mark in Chemistry is %d\n", mean[1]);
}
```

My understanding of it so far....

Define data types i, j, sum[2], mean[2] as integers.

Initialising the array....mark is data type int, the array should have 3 rows and 2 columns.

First for loop, j initialised at 0, condition: j has to be less than 2, update: add one onto the value of j. Sum of j = 0.

Also for 2nd loop, i initialised at 0, condition: i has to be less than 3, update: add one onto the value of i.

Similar for the next line that uses the for loop and value j.

I'm a bit confused about the syntax: 
sum[j] = sum[j] + mark[i] [j]; does this mean, work out the sum of j and add it to the marks contained in the array displayed as [i] and [j].

After this is completed then similar j loop though not sure how this interacts with the previous loops.

Mean calculated and values printed to the screen.

When I've looked at the worked example...
sum[0] = 0 and sum[1] = 0, I don't really understand why sum[1] is also 0.

Firstly, i=0 and j=0,

sum[0] = sum[0] + mark [0,0]

then j=1

sum[1]=sum[1]+mark[0,1]

then

i=1, j=0
sum[0] = sum[0] + mark [1,0]

then

sum[1] = sum[1]+mark[1,1]

then i = 2, j=0

sum [0] = sum[0]+ mark[2,0]

then

sum[1] = sum[1]+ mark[2,1]

What is confusing me a bit is how the loops are interacting with each other and the values of i and j throughout.

I know that the 2d array would be in a table (that I can't seem to format here).

Would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this.

Comment: "What is confusing me a bit is how the loops are interacting with each other and the values of i and j throughout.". Use a debugger to step through the code. Or even pen and paper.

Comment: A good debugger would be `gdb`.

Comment: This is a very basic programming knowledge...

Comment: Do you know what the program is actually doing? If you do not even understand that, replace `i` with `student_num` and replace `j` with `exam_num`. Then try to understand the code again. Remember that an array of length `n` has indices from 0 to `n-1`, meaning when `student_num` is 2, you're actually dealing with the 3rd student. The loops just prevent you from trying to deal with a 4th student or a 3rd exam when you only have the marks for 3 students and 2 exams.

Answer (score 2):

`sum[j] = sum[j] + mark[i][j];` can be simplified as `sum[j] += mark[i][j];`. It adds the contents of the cell at row `i`, column `j` of the 2D matrix `mark` to the `j`th element of array `sum`.

Accessing an element of a 2D array is written `mark[i][j]` in C, not `mark[i, j]`.

Note that `mark[i, j]` is not a syntax error: the expression `i, j` is a comma expression, evaluating `i`, then discarding it and evaluating `j`.  It is therefore the same as `mark[j]` which is not a matrix cell but a reference to the `j`th row of the 2D matrix.

Answer (score -4):

Nope, an array is in fact a pointer (aka an address). When you define `int sum[2]`, sum is the address of the first element of your array of two integer.

So sum is an `int*` or `int[]` (same).

Mark is an 2d array. Mark is in fact an array of array. So Mark contain addresses, and thoses addresses are the beggining of some arrays.

(In fact it can be different in the memory, but the compiler do the work).

Mark is a `int**`, or an address of address of int.

When you do:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        sum[j] = sum[j] + mark[i][j];
    }
}
```

It's like if you were saying

```
for each line i in the array, I want to do:
    for each value j in the line, I want to do:
        ...;
```

Like this, you work on every "line" (or column, visualize the way you want), and for every "line", you work on every value.

Comment: This is very confusing: *an array is in fact a pointer (aka an address)*. An array is **not** a pointer.  an array is an object that contains a series of values and a pointer is a variable that can contain the address of such an object.  A 2D array is simply an array of arrays. *So Mark contain addresses, and those addresses are the beginning of some arrays.* This is completely false. `mark` is **not** `int**`, it is an object containing 3 groups of 2 `int` values. No pointers involved. I rarely downvote answers, but this one is unhelpful.

Comment: Nope, it's true. An array is a pointer. Try to do printf("%p\n", sum);, you will see it yourself, it's an address. An array in memory, is just a contiguous area, but your variable, is the address of the first element. When you do sum[3], it's like *(sum + 3), and it's a pointer. You can also create an array with malloc. Or you can assign "int *ptr = sum" it will work without problem.

Comment: No, an array is not a pointer. An array expression is, in some but not all contexts, *converted* to a pointer expression. Try applying `sizeof` to an array object. Please read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c.FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com) before you continue to spread misinformation.

Comment: Arrays decay as pointers to their first element when used as expression operands, function arguments or return values. This useful trick does not **make** them pointers.  Arrays **have** an address, pointers are variables that **contain** an address.  Your mind representation of arrays and pointers is not precise enough: hinting that `mark` could be `int**` is a sign of confusion. Indirect arrays can indeed be implemented as arrays of pointers to arrays of objects, and they would be accessed with the same `mark[i][j]` syntax, but the memory layout would be very different.

Comment: `mark` is a two dimensional array. An `int**` would have to point to an object of type `int*`; the definition of `mark`creates no such pointer object.

Comment: @chqrlie: That's not the set of cases where array expressions are converted to pointer expressions. The conversion occurs *unless* the array expression is (a) the operand of unary `&`, (b) the operand of `sizeof`, or (c) a string literal in an initializer that initializes an array object.

Comment: @Ludonope: An *expression* of array type will be converted to a pointer type under most circumstances, but *arrays* are not pointers.

Comment: But when I do `int array[8]; printf("%ld\n", (long)array);` it still an address, why?

Comment: OK, I've found my answer, my bad, you were right! Thanks :)
(I didn't knew this website, it's nice http://c-faq.com/ )

Comment: The right way to print that address is `printf("%p\n", (void*)array);`